# panda value_counts show duplicate

Tags: pandas-groupby

Here is the code that I am using

```
all_data.groupby('BsmtFullBath').BsmtFullBath.count()
```

and the output is coming up as

```
BsmtFullBath
0     856
1     588
2      15
3       1
0     849
1     584
2      23
3       1
NA      2
Name: BsmtFullBath, dtype: int64
```

Expecting it to have a unique value for the each value, but "0" is coming two times.

Comment: can you provide dataset

Comment: Thanks for the comment, as i concat two frames, and one of the frames was having [1,2, 3] while the other one was having ['1', '2', '3'm 'NA'], that's why the value_counts was behaving weird. making astype('str') before the value_counts fix the issue.

Comment: As per  your comment i think you resolve your issue ,so you have remove this question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you want to get rid of the duplicated values, to use the map function just like in the example below, just ch

df_final['DC'] = df_final['DC'].map({'NO':0, 'WT':1, 'BU':2,'CT':3,'BT':4, 'CD':5})